# Multiply cell in dataframe based on character

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I multiply the Value by a factor 2 for each product having 2x?

```
Restaurant     Product     Value
1              a           3
1              b 2x        5
2              c           10
2              a 2x        2
```

I tried:

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(Value=case_when(
    Product =="2x"~ Value * 2,T~1))
```

Comment: `df$Value * (grepl("2x", df$Product) + 1L)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options with base R:

```
# option 1:
df$Value <- df$Value * (grepl("2x", df$Product) + 1L)

# option 2:
ix <- grepl("2x", df$Product)
df$Value[ix] <- df$Value[ix] * 2L
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   Restaurant Product Value
> 1          1       a     3
> 2          1    b 2x    10
> 3          2       c    10
> 4          2    a 2x     4
> ```

---

With [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = Value * (grepl("2x", Product) + 1L))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! :) What does the 1L mean in the code?

Comment: @Afke using `1L` tells R to use `1` as an integer; this gives you also a perfomance improvement over using `1`

Answer (score 3):

With tidyverse, just do :

```
df %>% mutate(x=(1+str_detect(Product,"2x"))*Value)
#  Restaurant Product Value  x
#1          1       a     3  3
#2          1    b 2x     5 10
#3          2       c    10 10
#4          2    a 2x     2  4
```

Answer (score 3):

First make a different column for those entries have 2x and then check that column which have 2x value and update the value column for the same

```
df<-mutate(df, x=strsplit(Product, split = " ")[[1]][2])
df$Value[df$x=="2x"]<-2*df$Value[df$x=="2x"]
```

Comment: sorry i missed something here use df$Value[df$x=="2x"]<-2*df$Value[df$x=="2x"]  i guess this will work